# How does this function accessing an array work?

Tags: shell-script, shell

I want to judge whether a string is in an array. I found the following function on Google. But I can't fully understand the meaning of this function.  In this function, `match` is assigned to the string to be matched. But where is the array saved? I added some output, and the variable `e` is always empty. I checked the meaning of `shift`. It shifts the variable to the left and shifts `$2` to `$1`. But there is no use of `$1` later. Does anyone know how this function works? Many thanks.

```
containsElement () {
      local e match="$1"
      echo $match
      echo $e
      shift
      echo $e
      echo $match
      for e; do [[ "$e" == "$match" ]] && return 0; done
      return 1
    }
array=("something to search for" " for" "a string" "test2000")
containsElement "a string" "${array[@]}"
echo $?
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From man bash:

> for *name* [ [ in [ *word* ... ] ] ; ] do *list* ; done
> ...
> If the "in *word*" is omitted, the for command  executes  *list*  once
> for  each positional parameter that is set

In reality, it will do the same as this:

```bsh
for e in "$@"; do
```

After the command `shift`, only the array elements remain in the positional parameters, which the `for` loop iterates over.